# JQuery $.post - returning value to PHP variable

Tags: php, jquery

I'm trying to post the value of a dynamic hidden input back to the same page using JQuery `$.post` with an intermediary php script.  The correct value is returned and shown in the alert in the code below, but I can't grab the value in the page via `$_POST`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('.case').click(function() {  
var caseId = $(this).find('input:hidden').val();
$.post("scripts/get_case.php", { case_pk: caseId },
   function(data) {
     alert("Respond: " + data);
   }); 
});
```

And on the same page:

```
$caseId = $_POST['case_pk'];

echo $caseId;
```

The intermediary php page (get_case.php):

```
<?php
$case = $_POST['case_pk'];
echo $case;
?>
```

The scenario is:

I have div buttons which are dynamically generated based on the number of `cases` in mysql db in a page `vmd.php`.  Each of these dynamically generated div buttons contains a hidden input with the corresponding value of the case id (`case_pk`).  On clicking one of these buttons, I want to run a mysql query based on the case id in `vmd.php`.  So my understanding is that I need to pass `case_pk` in the hidden fields via ajax back to the same page (`vmd.php`) and put that into a php variable that I can use in the query.

Comment: 1. `var_dump($_POST);` 2. Open dev tools in your browser and check what was sent

Comment: Because the *same page* is not re-loading. I think you want to update the markup using Ajax. Where you have alert statement, use `$('.some-item').html(data);`.

Comment: You're using AJAX to post a value to an intermediate script, which seems to be working. If you have the variable, why not place it where you need it with Javascript?  Exactly where are you checking $_POST['case']? Your variable name is different too (`case` or `case_pk`).

Comment: It's not really clear what you mean.  You can't access the value in `$_POST`, but you claim that the correct value is returned back from the AJAX call.  All that server-side code *does* is access the value in `$_POST`, so it seems to be working.  And I'm not sure at all what you're trying to do in the first PHP code example.  You don't know any form that posts a value to that.

Comment: OK, so how can I pass the value of the dynamically generated hidden fields back to a PHP variable to run a db query?

Comment: @PeterBrowne: You are doing that already.  `get_case.php` seems to be successfully receiving the value in `$_POST['case_pk']`, isn't it?  You say that the `alert()` in the client-side code displays the expected value, so `get_case.php` appears to be working.  You can do whatever you need to in server-side code from there.

Comment: I have changed the php on that page to $caseId = $_POST['case_pk']; echo $caseId; but still nothing.  Can you give me an example of how I can pass the value to the php variable on that same page?

Comment: @PeterBrowne: What do you mean by "that same page"?  It's not clear what you're trying to do.  When you post a value to a server-side resource (a "page" in this case), that value is available to that server-side resource.  If the "current page" needs to respond to it in some way then with AJAX you'd handle that response in the callback function of the AJAX call in JavaScript.  Which you're currently doing with the `alert()`.  Can you give a more complete example of what you're trying to do?  Because the code you've posted appears to be working.

Comment: @PeterBrowne: You don't have to POST the value specifically to the same page, you can POST it to any page. (Personally I tend to prefer handling AJAX requests as their own resources instead of the same "page" that produces a UI.) In your example you're POSTint it to `get_case.php`, and doing so successfully.  Have you tried running the database query from `get_case.php`? In the code posted that seems to be the ideal place to do it.

Comment: Sure, I understand that I can run the query in get_case.php successfully, but I would prefer to do the queries in vmd.php as there is a large amount of data that needs to be returned from not just one query but multiple dependant queries.  I don't understand why I can't pass back the value from get_case.php to vmd.php...

Comment: @David: I understand now that I need to run the queries in a seperate php script and return the values in a json array.  Do you want to put your last comment into an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not entirely clear which page you're *intending* to POST the value to, since the first of the two PHP samples doesn't appear to be used by anything.  The second of the two examples, however, seems to be working.  You're successfully performing an AJAX POST to another server-side resource (`get_case.php`) which is successfully receiving the value and echoing back that same value (given the description that the client-side `alert()` is behaving as expected).

So your server-side functionality in this case can be initiated by `get_case.php`, and any relevant response can then be sent back to the page and handled by client-side code in the callback function (where you currently have an `alert()`).

Keep in mind that it's not necessary to POST values to "the current page."  You can POST to any server-side resource.  Indeed, you may find it preferable to separate your server-side resources between pages which produce a UI (the "current page" in this case) and pages which act more like web services for AJAX calls and return only data (`get_case.php` in this case).  This can make it a lot easier to organize your code without having messy conditionals to determine if you should render a UI or JSON.

So a successful order of operations might go something like this:

1. User loads `page1.php` in their browser.
2. `page1.php` performs some server-side action and renders a UI.
3. In the UI there is JavaScript code which makes an AJAX call to `page2.php`.
4. `page2.php` performs some server-side action and renders JSON data.
5. The JavaScript code receives the JSON data and performs some client-side action.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that your "post" is something like

```
<input id="case_pk" name="case_pk" type="hidden" value="">
```

so in the success you should:

```
$('#case_pk').value(data);
```

in order to "reset/change" the value of that hidden input.